# Python String manipulation in a single line: Needs to get a new path without using extra variables

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list

```
import os
sys_path = os.getcwd()
print sys_path
input_file = 'input_file'
path = '/'.join(sys_path.split('/')[:-1].append(input_file))
```

the above code isn't working because the path gets 'None' values return from .append().

How can i do it without using any other variable in single line. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
path = '/'.join(sys_path.split('/')[:-1]+ [input_file])
```

but maybe overall

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys_path), input_file)
```

is better (no list operation and OS independent separator).

Answer (score -1):

JAugust, I don't know why .append() return None when used in single line, but replacing it to .**add**([value]) will work fine.

```
import os
sys_path = os.getcwd()
input_file = 'input_file'
path = '/'.join(sys_path.split('/')[:-1].__add__([input_file]))
print path
```